# Ошибка воспроизведения видео в VideoView

Tags: android, videoview

Не могу понять в чем проблема - в `Fragment` содержится один единственный `VideoView`

```
fragment_video.xml
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/video_fragment"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".FragmentVideo">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

В классе `FragmentVideo` все достаточно просто описано:

```
package com.rmr.ngusarov.hellomoon;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FragmentVideo extends Fragment{

    private MediaController mController;
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private Button mPlayButton;

    public FragmentVideo() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        String videoSource = "android.resource://com.rmr.ngusarov.hellomoon/" + R.raw.apollo_17_stroll;
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

        return v;
    }

}
```

Соответственно в папке res/raw находится mp4 файл с видеозаписью.
При запуске активности, которая является хостом для этого фрагмента, через некоторое время на экране смарфтона (nexus 5 android 6) возникает ошибка, оповещающая о невозможности воспроизведения видео.
Так же далее устройство зависает, если сразу не закрыть приложение и судя по тому что показывает logcat что то идет явно не так :

```
...
04-07 11:20:04.156 24051-24075/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
04-07 11:20:04.156 24051-24075/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
04-07 11:20:04.157 24051-24075/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
04-07 11:20:04.158 24051-24075/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
04-07 11:20:04.159 24051-24075/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
04-07 11:20:04.160 24051-24075/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
04-07 11:20:04.162 24051-24064/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
...
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я могу упустить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    videoView.start();
  }
});
```

Comment: Использовал ваш код, выведя videoView в переменные класса, и объявив содержимое в методе в onCreateView. Но к сожелению не помогло